# When do I load view data in a .net maui app?

Tags: c#, .net, maui

I'm seeing such an amount of conflicting advice on this so thought I would ask... How do I load data from an api in a .net maui view using a VM? Here is what I have seen, but none are reliable:

1. In the VM constructor - only gets called once so not an option
2. Use OnNavigatedTo - doesn't get called if the view is in an AppShell tab.
3. Use OnAppearing - doesn't get called if the view is in an AppShell tab.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide a specific example as your question is too vague and the topic too broad. What kind of API are we talking about? What data are you pulling and when do you need to update that data? Generally, you should never load data in the constructor, that's terrible advice, because constructor calls are blocking by nature and calls to external APIs usually should run asynchronously.

Comment: You may post some relevant code to help others understand this question. I saw an issue on Github might be help [When to load data](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/discussions/9248)

Answer (score 1):

> In the VM constructor - only gets called once so not an option

It is not an option, for much more important reasons than the times it is being called.

> Use OnNavigatedTo - doesn't get called if the view is in an AppShell
> tab.

Very good place, however, many times you will not want any updates. And MAUI right now cannot give much info about the navigation event, unless you write some extra code alone.

> Use OnNavigatedTo - doesn't get called if the view is in an AppShell
> tab.

Another very good place, but again, loading data takes time, you need to indicate background work accordingly (Activity indicator, error handling, etc...) Rarely I do API calls here.

I usually handle it by two approaches:

1.Once per page creation (**NOT IN CONSTR**) and again by user request. (Pull to refresh, etc...)

2.By server message that new data is available.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. When you say 'NOT IN CONSTR' - where would this be? Pull to refresh is fine but I need data to be there when the page loads with no user input. Also for the server message, how would you implement this? Are you talking about a signalR type of approach? Thanks

Comment: @BuckBuchanan The first time the page appears for example. Or the first time the page is navigated to. Or before the navigation. It really depends, on the situation I am. Try on Appearing, load the data, if its not loaded. Then add pull to refresh. Experiment. Whatever you do, do work in the constructor.